# Proof going in Circles

Tags: proof-verification

I am trying to show that if $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $m \ne 0$, then there exists an integer $k > 1$ such that $m \mid k$. However, I seem to be going in circles and arriving at incorrect conclusions.

If $m \ne 0$, then there exists some integer, $n$ such that $1 \le m \le n$ and $m \mid n$.

If $m \mid n$, then there exists some integer $k$ such that  $n=km$.

From here I am stuck. I am not sure if I can use the fact that $k=\frac{n}{m}$?

Or, I've considered the division algorithm ($m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $m >0$ then there exists some $q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n=qm+r$ where $0 \le r < m$), but again, I don't get anywhere with it.

It seems like this should be quite simple to show since I know that if $m \ne 0$ then there must be some integer, $k$, that it divides and $k = nm$ for some integer $n$. But, as above, I seem to get to a fraction instead.

Edit to Add: For the suggestion of simply picking any value of $k$ and showing it works - Is there any way to solve for $k$ so that it works for all values of $m$?

For example, can we say $k = j\cdot m$ and show $j$ is negative when $m$ is negative; and, that $j$ is positive when $m$ is positive (in order to ensure $>1$)?

Comment: k = 2m? Give an easy example that satifies?!

Comment: $2\mid 2$, $100\mid 100$, $-1\mid -1$, ...

Comment: Just take $k=2m$.

Comment: So - basically because I just have to show that one exists, I can create any $k$ I want so long as it works?

Comment: @Xammm - How does this account for $k>1$? I know $m \ne 0$, but not that $m>0$. So, how do we guarantee that $k$ is a positive integer?

Comment: @Math1 if $m>0$ take $k=2m$, if $m<0$ take $k=-2m$.

Comment: So, there is no way to find a value of $k$ that would work for all $m$?

Comment: @Math1 If $m > 0$, take *absolutely any* $k > 1$. If $m < 0$, take *absolutely any* $k < -1$. That's all there is to it.

Comment: You could, but there's really no need. Just make cases.